# Spring - aggregation - feed activity

Tags: spring, events, spring-data, aggregate

I am working with spring and a Postgresql database.

I have a Event table (exists differents types of events)
I have a sql query to shows events to one user, similar like this:

```
@Query( value = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.user.id = :userId ORDER BY e.date DESC")
Page<Event> findEvents(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

I would like to be able to aggregate events per type, when the dates are very close.
Something like this: "Your photo has 10 likes"

How do you solve these types of cases?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, Hibernates `@Formular` Annotation should be appropriate.

It could look like this:

```
@Formula(“(select count(b.someData) from table b where b.key = key)”)
private Integer someData;
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785